# How to convert a String to a float array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a `String` like this:

```
String volt = “[1.2, 3.1, 5.3]”;
```

How can I convert the `String` to a `float` array ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking - you haven't shown us an actual string.

Comment: String volt = "[1.99, 1.98, 1.98, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.98, 1.92 ]"

Comment: Can you add some information on what you have actually tried to do to convert this string in Java? Also I would suggest updating the question based on the other comments so that it is more clear what you are asking. i.e. string volt = "...." should be part of the original question. You can edit your question so that it is updated and relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you split the string into an array:

```
String str = "1.2, 3.1, 5.3, 4.5"; 
String[] arrOfStr = str.split(",");
```

Then you loop through the array and convert to floats:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
ArrayList <Double> volts = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrOfStr.length; i++) { 
    volts.add(Double.parseDouble(arrOfStr[i]));
}
System.out.println(volts);
```

Comment: The same, with split the app closes.

Comment: @LuisaGonzález What does your string look like?

Comment: but it is from a sqlite database:
String volt = cursor.getString(1);
 "[1.99, 1.98, 1.98, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.97, 1.98, 1.92 ]"

Comment: @LuisaGonzález Ok Try this:
 String[] arrOfStr = volt.substring(1, volt.length() -1).split(",");
Instead of:
String[] arrOfStr = str.split(",");
But if split is giving you trouble it might be that you are not actually dealing with a String, cast it to a String before you attempt to call split()

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.8 using Stream api:

```
//After removing squire bracket
String volt = "1.2, 3.1, 5.3, 4.5";
List<Float> list = Pattern.compile(", ")
                   .splitAsStream(volt)
                   .map (elem -> Float.parseFloat(elem))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming volt is a comma separated string.

```
  String volt = "1.2,3.1,5.3";

  String[] voltsToStrArray = volt.split(",");

  ArrayList<Float> voltsToFloatArray = new ArrayList<>();

  for(String strValue : voltsToStrArray) {
      voltsToFloatArray.add(Float.valueOf(strValue));
  }
```